# How to get array in form of String in json parsing?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have following json:

```
[{"status":1,
    "result":
           [{"description":"solve table",
            "completion_date":"0000-00-00",
             "status":"Checked",
             "hw_incomplete_students":["Rahul B. Thakur","Devendra R. Bhavsar"],
             "hw_incomplete_students_roll_no":["0","0"],
             "students_roll_no":["0","2","3","3"],
             "students":["Prakash K. Iear","sagar H pandit","sagar H pandit","sagar H pandit"],
             "to":"Division"
           }]
 }]
```

From this json result,i am getting `"description"`,`"status"`etc. But I am not able to get values of entities which have their content in array like `"students_roll_no"`,`"students"`. The value i am getting is in String but i want the array directly. How to deal with this? any suggestions?
   If I am not clear,please comment.

**EDIT 1:**
Below is the parsing which I have done:

```
JSONArray jarr;
    jarr = parse_json.parsearray(response);
    for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
            String std=new JSONObject(jarr.getString(i)).get("students") + "");

    \\same for others

    }
```

Now I get result as below=>

```
String std=["Prakash K. Iear","sagar H pandit","sagar H pandit","sagar H pandit"]
```

which is String. I want it as array.

Comment: There's something weird with the result: std is already an Array of Strings the way you wrote it (in wrong java syntax though).

Comment: Another thing, just for clarity: the jarr variable holds the content of the result array?

Comment: yes jarr contains result JSONArray

Comment: downvoter care to explain the reason

Answer (score 0):

I would use the method .getJsonArray(String name) and then cycle over the results to build what you need.

Comment: I have done with this. but i am getting result as String. I want that array directly

Comment: You should probably post the code because I cannot understand very well what you obtained (did you call .toString() on the resulting JSONArray object?).

Comment: parse_json.parsearray(response) is my function to parse given jason which returns JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use GSON to parse the json to an object wich has the arrayList.

```
Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<List<TestObject>>(){}.getType();
String s = gson.toJson(list, listOfTestObject);
List<TestObject> list2 = gson.fromJson(s, listOfTestObject);
```

[Gson Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples)

Comment: Should I use both Json and Gson?

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ is a site were you can convert your json to object classes

Comment: I have checked it but I need to convert my Json to Gson. I would prefer the json as it has been used in my whole project